# How can i use pdo group by and count

Tags: php, pdo

This is my sql_table :

[image]

i need this

How Many MODÜL X in between xx.xx.xxxx date - xx:xx time

Ex:

For 12.12.2023 11:30 
11 Unit Modül 1
3 Unit Modul 2 
4 Unit Modül 8

I try this but i cant. My english not well please help me.

Comment: You want to query how many `id_modul_ad` of value `MODÜL` there are between two datetimes, is that right? And one of the problems is that date and time are in separate columns

Comment: put in the code that u tried and failed

Comment: i want to check how many MODÜL1 how many MODÜL 2 etc. in a date + time.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<?php
$date = '11.12.2013';
$time = '16:60';
$a = $db->prepare("
select * from sinavliste 
where l_sinif_tarih='$tarih' and l_sinif_oturum='$time' 
group by l_modul_ad");
$a->execute(array());
$b = $a->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($b as $x){
echo $x['l_modul_ad'];
?>

i think its wrong.

i need this result:


l_modul_tarih(DATE) : 11.12.2013
l_modul_ad(MODÜL 1) : 10 Adet
l_modul_ad(MODÜL 2) : 2 Adet
l_modul_ad(MODÜL 3) : 5 Adet


l_modul_tarih(DATE) : 24.11.2014
l_modul_ad(MODÜL 1) : 9 Adet
l_modul_ad(MODÜL 2) : 4 Adet
l_modul_ad(MODÜL 3) : 1 Adet
l_modul_ad(MODÜL 4) : 7 Adet
```

thanks for everthing